# Append to ul and li elements to make them appear in the DOM

Tags: javascript, list, dom, appendchild, uitextcontenttype

Hi I tried to append the li and a to make them appear in the DOM
I tried to copy the text content but I don't know how to make the li and a appear in the new duplicated list.
The second menu should be appear in the "smallNavArea"

```
<nav>
<ul id="primaryNavigation">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="location.html">Menu</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<nav id="smallNavArea"></nav>
```

```
function duplicateMenu() {

let Menu = document.querySelectorAll('ul#primaryNavigation li a')


Menu.forEach(menuList => {
    let Li_Element = document.createElement('li')
    let newLink_Element = document.createElement('a')
    newLink_Element .setAttribute('href', menuList.getAttribute('href'))
    let MenuText = document.getElementById('primaryNavigation').textContent 
    
})
}

duplicateMenu()
```

Comment: Your function creates a new LI, but never appends it anywhere.

Comment: Where should the new menu appear?

Comment: Why do you need to duplicate the navigation menu?

Comment: Oh oops, It should be appear in this new area of the html <nav id="smallNavArea"></nav>

Comment: Do you have a `<ul>` there?

Comment: no. the area is blank

Comment: Duplicated the menu for phone nav bar, the original is for desktop

Comment: Reactive navigation is usually done with CSS media queries, not duplicating the menus.

Comment: this is an assignment to help us learn with DOM, so we don't use CSS media queries

Comment: so after I add the textcontent to get the element from the original nav bar..is there a way for me to append the li, and a to the text?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the `UL` in the destination DIV. Then you need to append the new link to the new LI, and append the new LI to the new UL.

```js
function duplicateMenu() {

  let Menu = document.querySelectorAll('ul#primaryNavigation li a')
  let smallNav = document.querySelector("#smallNavArea");
  let newUL = document.createElement("ul");
  smallNav.appendChild(newUL);

  Menu.forEach(menuList => {
    let Li_Element = document.createElement('li')
    let newLink_Element = document.createElement('a')
    newLink_Element.setAttribute('href', menuList.getAttribute('href'))
    newLink_Element.innerHTML = menuList.innerHTML;
    Li_Element.appendChild(newLink_Element);
    newUL.appendChild(Li_Element);
  })
}

duplicateMenu()
```

Comment: it's fine! I figure

Comment: By the way, I have a question: what does it mean when we set     newLink_Element.innerHTML = menuList.innerHTML ? I seem to understand why he said I need to create a UL part but kind of lost in this part

Comment: That's copying the HTML from the old link to the new link.